# API call to return a record based on a nested value

Tags: api, postman

I am attempting to find the account with room 101.  Room 101 is a nested value and I can't figure out how to write the query to only return the accont with room = 101.  Hopefully somebody knows the answer.

This API call:

https://{{fqdn}}/admin/scaffolds/accounts/index.json?api_key={{api-key}}

Returns these results:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": null,
    "login": "xbox1",
    "crypted_password": "$2a$11$0Wx3vC89gYaF/89mk66S1urZ2G.hm1LZDTYaVzyqCiMwlu8lzM11y",
    "salt": null,
    "state": "active",
    "first_name": "xbox",
    "last_name": "one",
    "email": "xbox1@test.com",
    "usage_plan_id": 1,
    "usage_minutes": null,
    "unlimited_usage_minutes": true,
    "usage_expiration": null,
    "no_usage_expiration": true,
    "automatic_login": true,
    "note": null,
    "logged_in_at": "2022-04-25T11:16:33.622-07:00",
    "created_at": "2022-04-25T05:22:09.259-07:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-04-25T12:23:10.472-07:00",
    "created_by": "tboyer",
    "updated_by": "expire_sessions",
    "mb_up": 56,
    "mb_down": 429,
    "pkts_up": 160309,
    "pkts_down": 325389,
    "usage_mb_up": null,
    "usage_mb_down": null,
    "unlimited_usage_mb_up": true,
    "unlimited_usage_mb_down": true,
    "company": null,
    "address1": null,
    "address2": null,
    "city": null,
    "region": null,
    "zip": null,
    "country": "US",
    "phone": null,
    "bill_at": null,
    "lock_version": 11,
    "charge_attempted_at": null,
    "lock_devices": false,
    "relative_usage_lifetime": null,
    "scratch": null,
    "portal_message": null,
    "max_devices": 1,
    "unlimited_devices": false,
    "max_sessions": 1,
    "unlimited_sessions": false,
    "max_dedicated_ips": 1,
    "account_group_id": 1,
    "email2": null,
    "pre_shared_key": "D71TP6QEH8YAS239",
    "phone_validation_code": null,
    "email_validation_code": null,
    "phone_validated": false,
    "email_validated": true,
    "phone_validation_code_expires_at": null,
    "email_validation_code_expires_at": null,
    "max_party_devices": 0,
    "unlimited_party_devices": false,
    "nt_password": "3b1b47e42e0463276e3ded6cef349f93",
    "upnp_enabled": true,
    "automatic_provision": false,
    "ips_are_static": true,
    "guid": null,
    "balance": "0.0",
    "full_name": "xbox one",
    "mb_down_consumed": 429,
    "mb_down_left": 0,
    "mb_up_consumed": 56,
    "mb_up_left": 0,
    "name": "xbox1",
    "quota": "unlimited",
    "total_utilization": null,
    "unlimited_max_devices": false,
    "unlimited_max_sessions": false,
    "account_group": {
      "id": 1,
      "policy_id": 3,
      "name": "Post-Auth",
      "priority": 4,
      "note": null,
      "created_at": "2022-04-25T06:00:19.161-07:00",
      "updated_at": "2022-04-25T06:01:11.936-07:00",
      "created_by": "tboyer",
      "updated_by": "puma: cluster worker 1: 92557",
      "scratch": null,
      "conference_id": null,
      "disable_enhanced_psk_security": false
    },
    "account_groups": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "policy_id": 3,
        "name": "Post-Auth",
        "priority": 4,
        "note": null,
        "created_at": "2022-04-25T06:00:19.161-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-25T06:01:11.936-07:00",
        "created_by": "tboyer",
        "updated_by": "puma: cluster worker 1: 92557",
        "scratch": null,
        "conference_id": null,
        "disable_enhanced_psk_security": false
      }
    ],
    "devices": [],
    "login_sessions": [],
    "media_converters": [],
    "pms_guests": [],
    "pms_rooms": [],
    "usage_plan": {
      "id": 1,
      "account_group_id": 1,
      "name": "test",
      "description": null,
      "currency": "USD",
      "recurring_method": "none",
      "recurring_day": null,
      "variable_recurring_day": true,
      "automatic_login": true,
      "note": null,
      "created_at": "2022-04-25T08:04:58.091-07:00",
      "updated_at": "2022-04-25T08:04:58.091-07:00",
      "created_by": "tboyer",
      "updated_by": "tboyer",
      "time_plan_id": null,
      "quota_plan_id": null,
      "usage_lifetime_time": null,
      "absolute_usage_lifetime": null,
      "unlimited_usage_lifetime": true,
      "no_usage_lifetime": false,
      "recurring_retry_grace_minutes": 1440,
      "recurring_fail_limit": 5,
      "prorate_credit": false,
      "permit_unpaid_ar": false,
      "pms_server_id": null,
      "lock_devices": false,
      "scratch": null,
      "max_sessions": 1,
      "max_devices": 1,
      "unlimited_devices": false,
      "unlimited_sessions": false,
      "usage_lifetime_time_unit": "days",
      "max_dedicated_ips": 0,
      "pms_guest_match_operator": "OR",
      "recurring_lifetime_time": null,
      "recurring_lifetime_time_unit": "months",
      "unlimited_recurring_lifetime": true,
      "sms_gateway_id": null,
      "validation_method": "none",
      "validation_grace_minutes": 0,
      "max_party_devices": 0,
      "unlimited_party_devices": false,
      "upnp_enabled": true,
      "automatic_provision": false,
      "conference_id": null,
      "ips_are_static": false,
      "base_price": null
    },
    "vlan_tag_assignments": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "type": null,
    "login": "xbox2",
    "crypted_password": "$2a$11$y20aajlZCxkGkJ1jL4lyTOvhEv0mHb9gazi03U1iqNzRSBckBdEAS",
    "salt": null,
    "state": "active",
    "first_name": "xbox",
    "last_name": "two",
    "email": "xbox2@test.com",
    "usage_plan_id": 1,
    "usage_minutes": null,
    "unlimited_usage_minutes": true,
    "usage_expiration": null,
    "no_usage_expiration": true,
    "automatic_login": true,
    "note": null,
    "logged_in_at": "2022-04-27T12:27:10.765-07:00",
    "created_at": "2022-04-25T05:22:37.257-07:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-04-29T07:35:44.872-07:00",
    "created_by": "tboyer",
    "updated_by": "tboyer",
    "mb_up": 253,
    "mb_down": 1826,
    "pkts_up": 758129,
    "pkts_down": 1516621,
    "usage_mb_up": null,
    "usage_mb_down": null,
    "unlimited_usage_mb_up": true,
    "unlimited_usage_mb_down": true,
    "company": null,
    "address1": null,
    "address2": null,
    "city": null,
    "region": null,
    "zip": null,
    "country": "US",
    "phone": null,
    "bill_at": null,
    "lock_version": 50,
    "charge_attempted_at": null,
    "lock_devices": false,
    "relative_usage_lifetime": null,
    "scratch": null,
    "portal_message": null,
    "max_devices": null,
    "unlimited_devices": true,
    "max_sessions": null,
    "unlimited_sessions": true,
    "max_dedicated_ips": 1,
    "account_group_id": 1,
    "email2": null,
    "pre_shared_key": "Z79LCS6NJREH3MGU",
    "phone_validation_code": null,
    "email_validation_code": null,
    "phone_validated": false,
    "email_validated": true,
    "phone_validation_code_expires_at": null,
    "email_validation_code_expires_at": null,
    "max_party_devices": 0,
    "unlimited_party_devices": false,
    "nt_password": "3b1b47e42e0463276e3ded6cef349f93",
    "upnp_enabled": true,
    "automatic_provision": false,
    "ips_are_static": false,
    "guid": null,
    "balance": "0.0",
    "full_name": "xbox two",
    "mb_down_consumed": 1826,
    "mb_down_left": 0,
    "mb_up_consumed": 253,
    "mb_up_left": 0,
    "name": "xbox2",
    "quota": "unlimited",
    "total_utilization": null,
    "unlimited_max_devices": true,
    "unlimited_max_sessions": true,
    "account_group": {
      "id": 1,
      "policy_id": 3,
      "name": "Post-Auth",
      "priority": 4,
      "note": null,
      "created_at": "2022-04-25T06:00:19.161-07:00",
      "updated_at": "2022-04-25T06:01:11.936-07:00",
      "created_by": "tboyer",
      "updated_by": "puma: cluster worker 1: 92557",
      "scratch": null,
      "conference_id": null,
      "disable_enhanced_psk_security": false
    },
    "account_groups": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "policy_id": 3,
        "name": "Post-Auth",
        "priority": 4,
        "note": null,
        "created_at": "2022-04-25T06:00:19.161-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-25T06:01:11.936-07:00",
        "created_by": "tboyer",
        "updated_by": "puma: cluster worker 1: 92557",
        "scratch": null,
        "conference_id": null,
        "disable_enhanced_psk_security": false
      }
    ],
    "devices": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "account_id": 2,
        "name": "MBP",
        "mac": "a0:ce:c8:ca:1f:e7",
        "note": null,
        "created_at": "2022-04-27T12:27:09.304-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-27T12:27:09.463-07:00",
        "created_by": "puma: cluster worker 0: 42604",
        "updated_by": "puma: cluster worker 0: 42604",
        "scratch": null,
        "lock_version": 1,
        "binat": false,
        "lan_party_id": null,
        "hidden_from_portal": false,
        "static_ip_id": null
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "account_id": 2,
        "name": "XboxOne",
        "mac": "bc:83:85:84:78:ad",
        "note": null,
        "created_at": "2022-04-25T15:35:16.803-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-29T07:35:44.881-07:00",
        "created_by": "puma: cluster worker 1: 82720",
        "updated_by": "puma: cluster worker 1: 50494",
        "scratch": null,
        "lock_version": 9,
        "binat": false,
        "lan_party_id": null,
        "hidden_from_portal": false,
        "static_ip_id": null
      }
    ],
    "login_sessions": [],
    "media_converters": [],
    "pms_guests": [],
    "pms_rooms": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "pms_server_id": null,
        "room": "101",
        "created_by": "tboyer",
        "updated_by": "tboyer",
        "created_at": "2022-04-26T14:54:28.306-07:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-30T05:05:18.384-07:00",
        "pms_property_id": null
      }
    ],
    "usage_plan": {
      "id": 1,
      "account_group_id": 1,
      "name": "test",
      "description": null,
      "currency": "USD",
      "recurring_method": "none",
      "recurring_day": null,
      "variable_recurring_day": true,
      "automatic_login": true,
      "note": null,
      "created_at": "2022-04-25T08:04:58.091-07:00",
      "updated_at": "2022-04-25T08:04:58.091-07:00",
      "created_by": "tboyer",
      "updated_by": "tboyer",
      "time_plan_id": null,
      "quota_plan_id": null,
      "usage_lifetime_time": null,
      "absolute_usage_lifetime": null,
      "unlimited_usage_lifetime": true,
      "no_usage_lifetime": false,
      "recurring_retry_grace_minutes": 1440,
      "recurring_fail_limit": 5,
      "prorate_credit": false,
      "permit_unpaid_ar": false,
      "pms_server_id": null,
      "lock_devices": false,
      "scratch": null,
      "max_sessions": 1,
      "max_devices": 1,
      "unlimited_devices": false,
      "unlimited_sessions": false,
      "usage_lifetime_time_unit": "days",
      "max_dedicated_ips": 0,
      "pms_guest_match_operator": "OR",
      "recurring_lifetime_time": null,
      "recurring_lifetime_time_unit": "months",
      "unlimited_recurring_lifetime": true,
      "sms_gateway_id": null,
      "validation_method": "none",
      "validation_grace_minutes": 0,
      "max_party_devices": 0,
      "unlimited_party_devices": false,
      "upnp_enabled": true,
      "automatic_provision": false,
      "conference_id": null,
      "ips_are_static": false,
      "base_price": null
    },
    "vlan_tag_assignments": []
  }
]
```

How can I write an API call that will return only the record with room:101?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the API endpoint you mentioned returns always all accounts. You need find out if endpoint accepts query parameters to filter accounts. If not, you need process returned JSON by yourself.

Comment: So, I can do this:  https://{{fqdn}}/admin/scaffolds/accounts/index.json?api_key={{api-key}}&login=xbox2 and it will return only one account.  However, if I try to do this: https://{{fqdn}}/admin/scaffolds/accounts/index.json?api_key={{api-key}}&room=101 it still returns the full list of accounts.

Comment: If an url contains query parameter, for example 'login', as you mentioned above and it will influence response from a server, it means that someone have programmed it. In other words, someone wrote code like this: "if there is parameter login then return only account with this login". But it doesn't mean that there must be code for parameter 'room'. For an API usually programmers make documentation where you can check allowed parameters. Try find out that documentation.